# Wrapper Height Adjustment above Navbar

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble achieving the following.    I would like to remove the white background color above my nav bar on the following page.   http://www.balfourautobody.com/

This way the logo will sit on the brick instead of on white background.

I have been playing around with it but can not seem to figure it out.

I understand that is probably a pretty simple question but I am stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The white background belongs to the wrapper element (#wrapper). You would also have to remove the box shadow.

Be aware that doing this will remove your content background as well so you'll have to add another in.

Answer (score 0):

Move your div with id="logo" before div with id="wrapper":

```
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

To remove white space above navbar, add to styles something like this:

```
#contact-details {
    margin: 10px;
}

#header {
    min-height: 10px;
}
```